# Help promote this site for Drupal related DevOps topics?

Tags: support, site-promotion

There is a question on [meta.drupal.SE](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/) about "**[Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3606/39516)**".

[Here is one of the answers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3644/39516) over there (disclosure: it's mine), to recommend [devops.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) for ***Questions*** related to "DevOps topic about Drupal". For those who want (and are able) to consider doing so, please help me "push" it over there.

To get an idea of the DevOps questions over there, have a look at these search results:

- [jenkins hasaccepted:no](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=jenkins%20hasaccepted%3Ano)
- [continuous hasaccepted:no](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=continuous%20hasaccepted%3Ano)

Hint: change '...:no' to '...:yes' is also interesting ...

Please reach out to whatever favorite SE site you have where there are similar promo ads, and post a similar answer of there (no credits due!).

Of course, if you're a Drupal.SE user also and like the idea, don't forget to help me reach the minimum voting balance of +6 (Kenorb, GoogleTorp, Adrian, where are you???).

Comment: In order to avoid such ads from being adversely regarded (as competing with / stealing audience from the respective sister sites) we could somehow present our site as a home for Q&As that would be DevOps-related but *off-topic* on those sites.

Comment: @DanCornilescu you mean a variation of [this](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3614/39516) I assume.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I failed to see it :)

Comment: Hm, maybe my suggestion is not so good, judging by the comments on the swrecs ad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice initiative! 
But IMHO we should wait with such ads until the private beta ends.

We're still missing the core of moderators while the rep levels for various privileges are [artificially lowered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/342636), potentially making it difficult to moderate a higher level of traffic normally expected in a public beta stage. See [Don't raise rep requirements to public beta until pro-tem moderators have been empowered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258433/dont-raise-rep-requirements-to-public-beta-until-pro-tem-moderators-have-been-e)

Side note: a while ago I also placed a few such ads for the Area51 proposal (which still indicate the private beta status). Maybe of interest would be how these ads were received by the different communities :)

- [Community Promotion Ads - 2017 - Software Engineering Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8429/community-promotion-ads-2017/8440#8440)
- [Community Promotion Ads - 2017 - Unix & Linux Meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/community-promotion-ads-2017/4350#4350)
- [Community Promotion Ads - 2017 - Server Fault Meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9028/community-promotion-ads-2017/9038#9038)

Comment: Yes you may have "some" point, however there is also something like "keep the momentum" ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens OK, you're 1-2 votes away from moderator tools access. I'll help when I get there ;)